# C: Logical error in scanning input

Tags: c, io

I have the following implementation of reading character matrix and printing it back. It works fine, but when I give matrix for it, it waits for another character and then outputs matrix properly. How can I fix it so that I would not need to input another character?

**Sample input**

```
3 4
0001
0110
1110
```

**Sample output**

```
0001
0110
1110
```

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m; /* n, m - dimensions of matrix */
    int i, j; /* i, j - iterators */
    char **matrix; /* matrix - matrix input */
    scanf ("%d %d\n", &n, &m);
    matrix = (char **) malloc (sizeof (char *) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * m);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            scanf ("%c ", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            printf ("%c", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the space *before* `%c`. If you have the whitespace after `%c`, scanf() would keep reading and ignoring all whitespaces. Hence you are forced to input a non-whitespace character.

Change:

```
    scanf ("%c ", &bitmap[i][j]);
```

to:

```
        scanf (" %c", &bitmap[i][j]);
```

Comment: by the way, what does whitespace before %c do?

Comment: It'll make scanf ignore any amount of whitespaces (such as \t, \n, space etc). If you have the *space* in the format stri ng after reading a char, then it'll read a char for `%c` but then keep ignoring all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

try omitting space in the scanf("%c "). terminal may be expecting a space for input

Comment: if i take it away, it will put newline characters into matrix

Comment: try %s instead of %c in scanf() it omitts any nonprintable scans from the buffer. tell if it works

Answer (score 0):

Before printing the characters, using `fflush(stdout);` might help. `printf()` and `scanf()` may sometimes be problematic when they are used together.

Answer (score 0):

```
        scanf ("%c", &bitmap[i][j]);
    }
    getchar();
```